# Remote Work: Asking for a Raise To Backfill Previous Benefits

Tags: raise, benefits

TLDR; Can I use the fact that I'm a remote employee and thus no longer use several company benefits (that I originally used when in a physical office i.e. Commuter reimbursement, free lunch on fridays) as a basis for a raise?

I've worked for my company for 4 years, 2 of them being remote.  I became a remote employee out of personal necessity to follow my spouse across the states for her new job (I'm assuming that it's a factor in the discussion that it was me who requested the remote work and not the employer).

So while this was beneficial to me and I am grateful for the opportunity, I can't help but wonder how much the company has saved from me becoming a remote employee.  When I signed on, I benefited from free catered lunches on Fridays, commuter reimbursement, occasional team happy hours etc.  Not to mention the fact that they didn't have to supply me with monitors, keyboard, desk, chair etc.

Is the fact that I no longer use / have access to these benefits a reasonable basis for a raise?

Comment: What happens if you decide to start using those benefits again?  Will you be willing to take a pay cut?

Comment: @sf02 excellent point...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Comment: Depending on how the company pays for the lunches and commuter benefit, they might not have saved anything by you becoming a remote employee. If they're paying a catering company based on having to feed 100 people or less, then having one less employee doesn't change the cost.

Comment: Besides the excellent answers you're already getting, it's worth pointing out that many employers see working from home itself as a "benefit" - they're giving you something that's of value to you by letting you work from home. So it doesn't really make sense to ask for more salary "because" of working from home, since working from home is already seen as being in your favor.

Comment: Isn't a complete lack of a commute better than commute reimbursement? How are you missing out on that benefit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Short answer? No.

Why? Because the benefits of working an office are meant to be compensation for working from that office and in theory should cancel out the cost of working from home.

For example:

- Commuter reimbursement - you don't have to travel therefore you are saving this amount already
- Free Lunches - You are at home and therefore able to make your own lunch at a far lower cost
- Occasional team happy hours - If you're willing to go in when an event has been organised you can probably still benefit from this (although I realise in your case this isn't possible). It's definitely a perk though, rather than something which should be seen as part of your overall compensation (see my answer on [this post](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/150123/couldnt-attend-holiday-party-should-i-ask-to-get-the-gift-offered-to-remote-em/150124#150124))
- Equipment - You can probably still ask for this to be supplied by your company, or to be reimbursed for a portion of it, but it would be a one off payment or expenses claim

At the end of the day, when someone decides to work from home they need to weigh up the benefits of working from home vs working in an office. How many hours a day do you save on your commute? There is your extra pay!

Answer (score 4):

> I can't help but wonder how much the company has saved from me
>   becoming a remote employee

That works both ways.

> Is the fact that I no longer use / have access to these benefits a
>   reasonable basis for a raise?

No, probably not. Negotiate a raise on your own merits, or on the business value you bring.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm assuming that it's a factor in the discussion that it was me who requested the remote work and not the employer

This is the key thing for me - while the company has probably saved some amount by not having in the office there is a very healthy argument to say that they haven't really *withdrawn* these benefits but rather that you've chosen not to make use of them. If you were still a local employee you'd still be getting the same benefits you had before.

If you didn't go to one of the office happy hours, or were on a day off on the day they did one of the free lunches you wouldn't be asking them to make the difference up in your paycheck at the end of the month - same deal.

Arguably this has been one of those enjoyable situations where everyone got some benefit out of the deal. And yes, part of that benefit to the employer will have been the slight savings on the benefits you mention, so essentially trying to revisit the deal to try and squeeze a bit more out of them at this point feels.. crass.

If you want a raise (and there's nothing wrong with that if you do) make your case in the same way you would if you weren't remote - on performance and value to the business.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the previous answers, but you should also consider the practical risk.

If you ask for a raise on the basis of being a remote worker your boss might respond with "It would be better overall for the company to have you working in the office, but I thought you preferred remote work. I have a desk, chair, and workstation I can assign for you next week. See you at 8 a.m. on Monday."

Answer (score 1):

> Is the fact that I no longer use / have access to these benefits a
>   reasonable basis for a raise?

Probably not.

Unless you work for a company that has cafeteria benefits (i.e., you have a fixed dollar amount to spend on any mix of benefits that works best for you), then you usually aren't free to trade in benefits you don't want for more salary.

You should ask though. It's unlikely to hurt and you might get lucky.